# Having without group by, with subquery

Tags: sql

I'm looking for the the rows that have namecounter = 3.
I tried using a where and having but both failed me, or am i doing something wrong?

This is my current SQL code:

```
SELECT refnam, tstring,(SELECT COUNT('refnam') FROM refdev rc
                        WHERE rc.refnam = r.refnam
                        ) as namecounter
FROM refdev r, OUTER texte t
WHERE r.sigtnr = t.textnr
ORDER BY refnam
```

Here's an example of my output at the moment:

```
AAU01   AANGEVRAAGD                                                                                             4
AAU01   ACTIEF                                                                                                  4
AAU01   UIT                                                                                                     4
AAU01   AANGEVRAAGD EN ACTIEF                                                                                   4
AB001   UIT                                                                                                     2
```

Comment: What is the `OUTER` supposed to do there? It doesn't seem valid SQL query.

Comment: Please post your schema so we don't have to guess your table structure.

Comment: The difference is 2292 vs 2268 rows. I'm sorry but i have no schema available :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT r.refnam, 
       t.tstring,
       rc.cnt namecounter,
       d.alarmzu
FROM refdev r
INNER JOIN (SELECT refnam, 
                   COUNT(*) cnt
              FROM refdev rc
          GROUP BY refnam
           ) rc 
        ON rc.refnam = r.refnam
LEFT OUTER JOIN texte t
             ON r.sigtnr = t.textnr
JOIN devtzu d ON d.zustnr = r.zustnr
LEFT OUTER JOIN refdev_DEF RD ON d.dvtypnr = RD.dvtypnr
WHERE r.refnam = RD.refnam
AND rc.cnt = 3
ORDER BY r.refnam
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT r.refnam, 
       t.tstring,
       rc.cnt namecounter
FROM refdev r
INNER JOIN (SELECT refnam, 
                   COUNT(*) cnt
              FROM refdev rc
          GROUP BY refnam
           ) rc 
        ON rc.refnam = r.refnam
LEFT OUTER JOIN texte t
             ON r.sigtnr = t.textnr
WHERE rc.cnt = 3
ORDER BY r.refnam
```

Comment: ERROR: Ambiguous column (refnam).
Error Code: -324

Comment: Then add aliases. You should have in the original query, too!

Comment: I dont understand what you mean ? the aliases here are R and RC

Comment: Sorry, I meant prefix columns with table aliases: `SELECT r.refnam, t.tstring`

Comment: Nice. And there is no need for `COUNT('refnam')`. `COUNT(*)` should work.

Comment: fixed the query, thanks @ypercube for the support :)

Comment: Hi guys, i'm looking for a way to add this to the code:
         SELECT d.alarmzu
   FROM devtzu d, OUTER refdev_DEF RD          
         WHERE D.zustnr = R.zustnr 
         AND D.dvtypnr = RD.dvtypnr AND R.refnam = RD.refnam

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? you want to get only the refnam returned from the first query?

Comment: @mucio How do you mean ? i want the first query (the one above), but this time also displaying alarmzu, and, the necessary join, + a join with refdev_DEF.

Answer (score 1):

As the subquery returns a column of your query, WHERE is right for this. I don't understand the "OUTER" thing as ypercube commented.

This should function:

```
SELECT refnam, tstring, COUNT(*) as namecounter
FROM refdev r, texte t
WHERE r.sigtnr = t.textnr
GROUP BY refnam, tstring
HAVING COUNT(*)=3
ORDER BY refnam
```

Comment: ERROR: Column (namecounter) not found in any table in the query
(or SLV is undefined).
Error Code: -217

Comment: I edited the post - in my opinion there is no need for a subquery. This would function on MS SQL Server for sure, but of course I can't guarantee this for a 10yo informix database...

Comment: This would not run in SQL-Server (you use `tstring` in the Select list while it's not in the GROUP BY list.) And the `GROUP BY` might result in different number of rows than the OP's query.

Comment: @ypercube I obviously forgot tstring in the group by list, yes, and maybe the count should be changed to `count(*)`, but then it would work out exactly like the OP wanted, and it's much more clear than the accepted answer.

Comment: I don't think so. A group by usually results in less rows (unless you group by a primary/unique key.)

Comment: Yes, a group by has the purpose of grouping things :-) As far as I understood, the OP wanted a list of refnam & tstring-combinations with the number of occurrences. Thats exactly what he gets.

Comment: Using this query i get only 4 rows as a result oO

Comment: Well, this would mean that you only have 4 different combinations of refnam and tstring that occur 3 times in your dataset. If you omit the HAVING part, you would see all the _different_ combinations and how often they occur in your dataset.